# Return Array from dataprovider to @Test method

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have created a Selenium  framework with TestNG. In this @Dataprovider contain set of code that reads data from excel and return this value in arrayform to @test.

```
@Test(dataProvider="createData1")
private  void login (String data, String data1) throws IOException{}

@DataProvider
public static String [][] createData1() throws IOException{

     String Scenarioname=new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getSimpleName();
     return  xls.readvalues(Scenarioname,"testdata");

}
```

Since login Test case has two inputs so method Login has two attributes.
Likewise if register Test case has 5 input then register method will have 5 attributes.
But  I want to create a standard way  in a manner so that when I return array from @dataprovider. Then @test method should read value dynamically rather than I mentioned number of attributes for each method.

Answer (score 3):

Your `@DataProvider` can return `Object[][]` instead of `String[][]`. So you can return scenario specification on first place and Object with user data on second place. Something like:

```
return new Object[][] {
    {"My Scenario1", new MyUserDataObject("name1", "password1", "male")}, 
    {"My Scenario2", new MyUserDataObject("name2", "password2", "female")}
};
```

and test method signature will be:
`login(String scenarioName, MyUserDataObject userData)`

Then test can read all mandatory data from `userData` parameter.

**Edit:**

Parametrized test got simple value as parameter so there is no userData[0][0] (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

@BeforeMethod doesn't support @DataProviders in TestNG (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/3Kny3qTVdmg)