# Need an alternate approach to get TestNG dataprovider arguments

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am reading data from *excel* using **data provider**, which has some 25 odd columns and 250 odd rows. I am reading and returning `Object[][]` from data provider.
    In turn I have to declare so 25 arguments in my test method For example

```
@Test(groups = { "regressionTest" }, dataProvider = "testDP")
public void testDP(String statusResponse, String statusHeader, String reposnseID, String responseConetent ..... String lastElement)

And the value of arguments are different for different test methods of test class. All I want, is not to declare 25 arguments every time I am writing a seperate test method, rather a approach similar to passing an object of class would be great.

//like having a POJO Class
@Test(groups = { "regressionTest" }, dataProvider = "testDP")
public void testDP(Class obj ){

//accessing the variables with getter/setter methods.
obj.getstatusHeader();
obj.getstatusResponse();
etc...
}
```

Thanks,

Vinod Baradwaj

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return Array from dataprovider to @Test method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698723/return-array-from-dataprovider-to-test-method)

Comment: If you are returning `Obejct[][]` you can in fact return any `Object` and change `@Test` method signature to that object. Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29699369/4786420